# how to change a var env value with nix

Tags: nix

here is my default.nix:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {}; {
  cimgEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "cimgdev";
  buildInputs = [ pkgconfig stdenv cimg xorg.libX11 boost jdk gradle (opencv4.override { enableGtk2 = true; })];
};
environment.variables = rec {
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/nix/store/j71chi4b06bh8rpd5611d6q8asrwf9z6-opencv-4.7.0/lib/";
};
}
```

but when after nix-shell i do a echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

i have nothing just an empty string

Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713707/nix-shell-how-to-specify-a-custom-environment-variable

Answer (score 1):

What you likely want is this `default.nix`:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  opencv4 = pkgs.opencv4.override {enableGtk2 = true;};
in
  pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "cimgdev";
    buildInputs = with pkgs; [pkgconfig stdenv cimg xorg.libX11 boost jdk gradle opencv4];
    shellHook = ''
      export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${opencv4}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
    '';
  }
```

If you want to know *why* this works and your code doesn't, read on:

A derivation in Nix is essentially just a set of instructions, which tells Nix how to build a package. A derivation consists of a name, a builder which is run during the build process, and a system where it can be built on. It may also contain any other attributes, which are passed to the builder as environment variables.

`nix-shell` takes a derivation (in `default.nix` or `shell.nix`) as input, and runs an interactive shell the same way the builder would be called, so with all the attributes exposed as env vars. It additionally reads the `shellHook` and executes the commands in there before running the shell.

The reason we can't directly set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` without a `shellHook` is that it'd overwrite any previous values, instead of adding to it.

I also changed your code to reference the `opencv4` package in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (with your override) instead of directly referencing the store path, because with your method it'd break if the package (or one of its dependencies) ever got updated.